# im trying to remove the double post image

Tags: php, css, wordpress

when you go to:

http://dageniusmarketer.com/

you will see the posts have 2 images.  I'm trying to remove the one on the bottom.

I initially added

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail( $size, $attr ); ?>
```

for the main post image, as I wasn't getting the placement I wanted, which was ABOVE the post statistics. Now that I have it above the statistics, I still have the original image, and I want to remove it.

I'm trying to play with the class `.wp-image`,

but that isn't giving me any sort of luck.  I just want to remove the 2nd duplicate image underneath the statistics and keep whatever other images I may wish to write into my post body in the future.  How do I do this?

edit: here is my php code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="main">
    <div id="content">

    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <!-- item -->
        <div class="item entry" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
            <div class="itemhead">
                <h1>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                </h1>
                <?php the_post_thumbnail( $size, $attr ); ?>
                <div class="postStatsContainer">
                    <div class="postViews">100 Views</div>
                    <div class="slash"></div>
                    <div class="postShares">100 Shares</div>
                    <div class="slash"></div>
                    <div class="postComments">100 Comments</div>
                    <div class="slash"></div>
                    <div class="date"><?php the_time('M jS, Y') ?></div>
                </div>
                <div style="clear: both"></div>
                <!--<div class="readMore_Container">-->                       
                <?php the_content('Read More  &raquo;'); ?>
                <div class="postCounter">
                    <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-2x"></i>#200
                </div>
                <div class="metadata" style="clear:both;">
                    <div class="TagIcon"></div>
                    Filed under 
                    <span class="category"><?php the_category(', ') ?></span> |
                    <?php edit_post_link('Edit', '', ' | '); ?>
                    <?php comments_popup_link('Comment (0)', ' Comment (1)', 'Comments (%)'); ?>
                </div>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end item -->
        <?php comments_template(); // Get wp-comments.php template ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <div class="navigation">
            <div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Previous Entries') ?></div>
            <div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link('Next Entries &raquo;') ?></div>
            <p> </p>
        </div>
    <?php else : ?>
        <h2 class="center">Not Found</h2>
        <p class="center">Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn't here.</p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <!-- end content -->
</div>
<div id="primary">
    <?php include(TEMPLATEPATH."/l_sidebar.php");?>
</div>
<div id="secondary">
    <?php include(TEMPLATEPATH."/r_sidebar.php");?>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Solving this issue with `css` is a really bad practice. Instead of hiding it just try to understand why does it happen. Share your php code please.

Comment: check the edited code, i just added it

Comment: It seems that the image itself is being added to your post's content since the image is being added as `<p><a href=".."><img ...></a></p>` right after the `<div style="clear:both"></div>` (according to `view source`). 1) Check in the admin panel that you're not setting the image in the post's content. 2) You might enabled a function that `filters` the post's content and adds the image.

Comment: i added the image initially the way you normally would when you write a post, by inserting image from media gallery.  Now that i have 2, is there a simple way for me to write a line of code to remove the bottom one?

Comment: The easier way isn't the right way. You can do it with css but as mentioned above - it's a bad practice. Consider manually removing it from the posts' contents. Back in the days you've should use a `filter` to automatically add the image instead of manually inserting it.

Comment: ill take bad practice for now then, because i have wayyy too many posts to go into each of them one by one to remove it.  Ill accept it as bad form going forward and will refrain, but for right now, i just need to remove it from what is there already.  What is the proper css for this? i know there is wp-image-1234, wp-image-5678, but that isn't practical to write a rule for each post that i have....is there some sort of blanket to target that wp-image class overall and remove it?

Comment: `.itemhead p a img {  display: none;}` but make sure you use this css code only on index pages, if you'd use it on a post's (single) page - it might hide other images. Update me if it did the trick so i'd write an answer.

Comment: it seems to somewhat work....what i realize is that all the posts with the image have to be encapsulated within an <a> tag for the effect to take place.  The double display is on images that dont have the <a> tag.

Comment: yes, you can alter it to `.itemhead p img{display:none;}` as well.

Comment: ill probably just go with a just in case i want to put other images in my post in the future.

Comment: May I write it as an answer?

Comment: there seem to be some inconsistencies in play with the code, as MOST posts render correctly...but a few others show no image, others show my stats on top of the image....not sure why